# Excel VBA Automation Error second time code runs

Tags: vba, excel, automation, runtime-error

In VBA Excel I get an Automation Error the second time I run my code.
It is as follows:

```
Sheets("Panel Resumen").Select
Rows("55:69").Select
Selection.Copy
Rows("55:55").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
Range("D25").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

And it triggers the error in the line

```
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

I researched and got to this link https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/178510/excel-automation-fails-second-time-code-runs
but I don't get which is the object I am failing to call

Comment: See [how to avoid Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) and probably that will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without using `Select`, this should solve it I think:

```
With Sheets("Panel Resumen")
    .Rows("55:69").Copy
    .Rows("55:55").Insert Shift:=xlDown
End With
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```